# How to remove inline style using functions.php (Wordpress / Woocommerce )

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The Stripe plugin adds an **inline style** to a div (style="display:block;"). How can I permanently remove or disable an inline style using functions.php. I want to change it to "display: none").

Regards, Konrad

```html
<div class="payment_box payment_method_paypal" style="display:block;">
  <p>
    Płać z PayPal; możesz zapłacić kartą kredytową jeśli nie masz konta PayPal.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: First and foremost, determine if that style is in the HTML (view source) or the DOM (inspect).

Comment: @chris-hass - My question is about a problem in Wordpress :)

Comment: Yes Mousebucks, I know that. But if the style is on the HTML tag, the fix can happen in PHP, however if the style is only in the rendered output (the DOM) then you’ll need to solve this in JavaScript. Also, your question says that you want to change it from `display: none` to `display: none` which are the same.

Comment: @chris-hass I don't know how this plugin adds the code (possibly via a php file). I want to remove the description in the red box from my checkout page - see sceen [https://prnt.sc/1a0wmh8]. You can see the page at https://cutt.ly/pmY4uDK You need to add a product to the cart and go to the "checkout"
P.S I'm sorry for my mistake. The plugin adds an inline style "display: block" (I changed it).